# Does declaring an existing variable without 'var' make it a global var or just change the value?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var stop = false
if (!$(this).val()) {
    stop = true
}
```

Does the 'stop = true' declaration pass the variable back as global, or merely change the value of it - or something completely new!

Comment: It looks up the scope chain, and the first one it finds, it changes. If it doesn't find one, it declares a global variable. This could've easily been tested - you already have code set up, and it could be expanded to test a bigger scope chain, as well as variables not being defined (in between, or globally)

Comment: if it's defined, it updates the global, if it's new, it creates the global.

Comment: If a variable is already declared by that name somewhere higher in scope, then it is not a variable declaration, it is an assignment.

Comment: How would you go about testing this @Ian? I am fairly new to global knowledge!

Comment: How to test: ``function(){var stop = false
if (!$(this).val()) {
    stop = true
}}(); console.log(stop);``.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704778/javascript-array-scope-issue/16705561#16705561

Comment: @Halcyon21 Use the code you have! Put it in the global scope! Then, put it in a function (or nested functions) and try it. Obviously, you can't always use `$(this).val()` because `this` is specific, but simple conditions and values would work fine

Comment: @Halcyon21 you can test your code at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here's a test, it prints 'native code' - does that have specific meaning? http://jsfiddle.net/6QvdW/

Comment: Lets assume it would create a global variable instead of assigning a value... how would you ever change the value of a local variable?

Comment: Felix, well, rather than 'change' the value, overwrite it.

Comment: @Halcyon21 what do you see as the functional difference between _changing_ a variable and _overwriting_ one?

Comment: What's the difference? Btw, regarding your fiddle, `stop` is an existing global variable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.stop.

Comment: @FelixKling Exactly... And that's interesting to know, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stop = true` will change the value of the variable, in this case.

Keep in mind function scope. If you use `var` within a function, the declared variable will not be in the global scope.

if you, for example, had this:

```
var stop = false;
function foo() {
    var stop = true;
}
```

calling `foo()` would not change the value of `stop`. Now there is a local `stop`, and a global `stop`. However...

```
var stop = false;
function foo() {
    stop = true;
}
```

now, when calling `foo()`, `stop` will have its value changed.